# ondrop ondragover - Uncaught ReferenceError: ondrop is not defined - angular - html5 draggable

Tags: angularjs, html

I try to implement html5 drag and drop with angular.

The code is:

```
<div ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.drop = function(e) { console.log('a drop') };
```

This leads to the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: drop is not defined

Exchanging `'ondrop'` with `'ng-click'` makes it work, so there is nothing missing in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ondrop` is a HTML attribute, therefore it expects the given function to be global, as opposed to angular directives such as `ng-click` which expect the callbacks to be published on the `$scope`.

Comment: is there a way to put the function on the global scope? would it be the `$rootscope` then?

Comment: I believe it would be `$window.myGlobalFunction` ?

Comment: Can you pls explain how to make this worked?

Answer (score 2):

You can use non angular events by connecting functions, that fire in that events to your scope. In this case:

```
ondrop='angular.element(document.getElementById("Id of element with ngController,or ngView(if you use router)")).scope().drop(event)'
```

Here I modified the drag and drop example from W3Schools:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
#div1, #div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

      <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl" id="myContrId">
    <div id="div1" ondrop='angular.element(document.getElementById("myContrId")).scope().drop(event)' ondragover='angular.element(document.getElementById("myContrId")).scope().allowDrop(event)'>
      <img src="https://diethelper.xyz/DHadmin/images/logo2w.png" draggable="true" ondragstart='angular.element(document.getElementById("myContrId")).scope().drag(event);' id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
    </div>

    <div id="div2" ondrop='angular.element(document.getElementById("myContrId")).scope().drop(event)' ondragover='angular.element(document.getElementById("myContrId")).scope().allowDrop(event)'></div>
  </div>
      <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
          $scope.allowDrop = function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
          }

          $scope.drag = function(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
          }

          $scope.drop = function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
          }
        });
      </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click` is a directive defined by angular itself. `ondrop`, is as far as I'm aware not part of angular's standard library.  You will need to define a new directive in order to get the functionality you want.  I would recommend checking out this blog post
http://blog.parkji.co.uk/2013/08/11/native-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Thanks man. The blog post was what I needed. Only found this `getElementById(..).scope()` advices which didn't help b/c the scope is `undefined` unless you're running your app in debug mode. Ended up writing my own directive oriented towards the one in the blog post.